# How to redirect every sitemaps sections to another url using NGINX proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, wildcard, sitemap, proxypass

I would like to redirect all our sitemap sections the same way we did for the root one.

```
        location = /sitemap.xml {
            proxy_pass https://redacted.fr/sitemap.xml;
        }
```

So I would like to do the same for, let say, sitemap-group1.xml but I can't write it down to NGINX like the root one as it's dynamic.
I think what would help is to have a wildcard and get the path to proxy_pass, but I have no idea how.

EDIT: My only goal is to `proxy_pass` /sitemap*.xml to https://redacted.fr/sitemap*.xml

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly filenames should be proxied that way? Anything like `sitemap-*.xml`?

Comment: @IvanShatsky You again :) Yes that's it. Check the EDIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the regex matching location block:

```
location ~ ^/sitemap[^/]*\.xml$ {
    proxy_pass https://redacted.fr;
}
```

If you have any other regex matching locations (locations with `~` modifier), take into account that the first matched location is used for the request processing, so I suggest to put this one before any other of regex matching locations. If you want case-insensitive matching, use `~*` instead of `~`.